# creating tables with FMDB on iPhone doesn't work

Tags: iphone, ios, sqlite, fmdb

i just tried to create a database in my iPhone app and couldn't build it.
i used following tutorial: [tutorial](http://www.icodeblog.com/2011/11/04/simple-sqlite-database-interaction-using-fmdb/)

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *docsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *path = [docsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"database.sqlite"];
    FMDatabase *database = [FMDatabase databaseWithPath:path];
    [database open];
```

but when running the app i get following error message:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FMDatabase", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Is it because iam using a 64bit system? 
Just were looking for another version of FMDB but could only find the one on gitHub [FMDB repository](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure FMDataBase.m is in your compile sources in the 'Build Phases' section

Comment: i inserted all files that are needed into my project. They are all inside the "Supporting Files"-Folder, so should be found. For me it sounds like it can access the FMDB-Files but there seems to be a problem inside. 
I now started to solve the problem without any rapper with following tutorial http://www.iosdevelopment.be/sqlite-tutorial/. But i would like to know why this problem occures

Comment: that's not true, sometimes they are in your supporting files, but not in your 'Compile Sources'. Just make sure it shows up in the section like this http://cl.ly/H5XK it should say FMDataBase.m there

Comment: realy interesting, just learned something new :).
The app does now start correctly but still brings up the message warning: no rule to process file '$(PROJECT_DIR)/niceTry4/FMDatabase.h' of type sourcecode.c.h for architecture i386
I get this warning message for each FMDB H-File i inserted.

Comment: @xandruCea The new URL for the SQLite tutorial is now: http://www.apptite.be/tutorial_ios_sqlite.php

Comment: @LucWOllants Thanks for the link. I just found it some months before and since than i never had problems with creating databases again. There might be some other Frameworks that make working with the database easier, but this tutorials works perfectly for me